# Unexpected redux .filter result

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx, redux-thunk

So going straight to the question, I've a filter list in my redux store, and there are filters which will be added and removed from it.

adding filter as follows:

```
case ADD_FILTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: [
          ...state.filters,
          action.filter
        ]
      };
```

is working as expected. but when removing a filter:

```
case REMOVE_FILTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: state.filters.filter(
          filter => filter.type !== action.filter.type && filter.name !== action.filter.name
        )
      };
```

will remove all of filters from my list!

here is a sample representation of filters:

```
{
    {
        type: 'sampleType1'
        name: 'value1'
    },
    {
        type: 'sampleType2'
        name: 'value1'
    },
    {
        type: 'sampleStatus1'
        name: 'value2'
    },
    {
        type: 'sampleStatus2'
        name: 'value3'
    },
}
```

and actions:

```
export function addFilter(filter) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_FILTER,
      filter
    });

    dispatch(load());
  };
}
```

,

```
export function removeFilter(filter) {
  console.log(filter);
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REMOVE_FILTER,
      filter
    });

    dispatch(load());
  };
}
```

I'm suspecting that there must be a problem with `.filter()` function.

I hope that I've explained everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove the filter specified, you should be using the or `||` operator:

```
filter => filter.type !== action.filter.type || filter.name !== action.filter.name
```

Comment: It seems that its working, but logically thinking, if I'm correct, this will say "Filter type not equal to Action's Filter type, or, Filter name not equal to Action's Filter name". Which will remove every filter that fits to this argument.

Now, I have a filter object (type=sampleType2, name=value1) it will also remove the first filter object from store (type=sampleType1, name=value1).

That's not what I expect.

Comment: The filter with (type=sampleType1, name=value1) will not be removed because `filter.type !== action.filter.type` returns true, making the whole statement true and retaining the element in the array.